# How to choose a particular location in map using appium

Tags: google-maps, appium

please help me to choose a particular location("oxford
    university",London) in google map using appium

Comment: try this `AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(remoteAdress, capabilities);
Location loc = new Location(20.0, 12.5, 1000);  // latitude, longitude, altitude
driver.setLocation(loc);`

Comment: @jyotsana namdev : you are working on a simulator or real device?

Comment: I am working with nexus 5